# Is the set of monic cubic polynomials with three distinct roots in [-1,1] connected?

Tags: real-analysis, polynomials, connectedness

Let $A$ be the set of points $(a,b,c)$ such that $x^3+ax^2+bx+c$ has $3$ distinct real roots in $[-1,1]$. Is $A$ connected?

Edit: This is a question on my homework that I have been stuck on for a while. There is just very little intuition for me when it comes to connected sets.

I have considered using the discriminant in its various forms to try and find two separating sets but I can't seem to find the sets explicitly.

I have also observed that removing the distinct requirement makes the set connected as I can define a continuous function from the roots to the coefficients and $[-1,1]^3$ is connected. Removing the plane $r_1=r_2$ in $[-1,1]^3$ seems to disconnect the sets so my guess is that it also disconnects the set $A$, but I'm again unable to determine the explicit separation.

Comment: Please add context to your problem statement.  Is it perhaps an exercise intended to reinforce understanding of a recently studied topic?

Comment: A small insight that can be usefull (I have not pushed the reasoning further): a necessary condition is that $f'$ vanishes twice in $(-1,1)$.

Comment: The set is path connected and hence connected. Hint: given any two such polynomials $f_0, f_1$, consider a family of polynomials $f_t : t \in [0,1]$ obtained by "interpolating" the roots "linearly".

Answer (score 1):

**Hint:** Let $r_1$, $r_2$ and $r_3$ be the roots. Consider the discriminant $$\Delta = (r_1-r_2)(r_1-r_3)(r_2-r_3).$$Note that $\Delta \neq 0$ if and only if $r_1$, $r_2$ and $r_3$ are pairwise distinct. Now use Vieta's relations $$r_1+r_2+r_3 = -a, \quad r_1r_2+r_1r_3+r_2r_3 = b, \quad r_1r_2r_3=c$$to write $\Delta$ as a function $\Delta = \Delta(a,b,c)$. Recognize what the equation $\Delta(a,b,c) = 0$ describes in the $abc$-space. I expect the answer to become somewhat clear then.

Comment: I did consider this approach. However, I found it really difficult to understand the surface defined by $$\Delta(a,b,c)$$ as the expression was nonlinear. Is there something obvious that I'm missing?